# Selecting an edge without vertices and deleting it

Tags: vertices, edges

I want to select an edge that is hanging in mid-air, but can’t do it. A problem occurred while deleting the extra vertices, and now only an edge is left. Is there a way to only select an edge and delete it? This edge is a part of an icing object. This edge has no vertices connected.

[image: Spot the thin strip just below the edge of icing]

[image: That edge cannot be selected in edit mode]

[image: That edge can be selected in object mode]

[image: How odd it looks]

That edge can't be selected as a whole in edit mode, but it can be selected in object mode.
You can see a thin strip here. How do I select it and delete it?

Comment: Could you please share your .blend file so we can better analyze the problem? Now we can only guess. If you can't share the .blend file maybe you could share images of your outliner and of your object in Edit mode.

Comment: Hello :). Every edge has at least two vertices. You need to switch to Edit Mode > Vertex selection mode to see them :).

Comment: @Joonas see the images. I'll send more if needed. File sharing is taking too much of time

Comment: What happens if you select the strip in object mode, toggle to edit mode and press 1 (Top row, not keypad)? Can you then see the vertices?

Comment: @Joonas that strip is not a separate object, so if the go to select it, the whole icing gets selected. Actually that strip is itself not selectable. Selecting the icing object selects the strip as well as the icing. I’ll still try doing it

Comment: Mayby you should just share the .blend file. The problem could be solved quite a lot faster.

Comment: @Joonas I'm requesting u to correct the problem if u can. Please don't change anything, just correct the problem if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you at least increase the shadow size in cycles? I can’t understand how to do that. It should look like             https://youtu.be/5lr8QnR5WWU

Comment: To improve the shadow you need to bring the point lamp closer to the doughnut and decrease its Radius,

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the "Delete Loose" option in Edit Mode >  Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose.

It is easier than having to select every floating vertices !

I'm not an expert, but I hope this helps

[image]